# Can someone explain "{ t '07:32:00' }" please?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I recently ran across this:

```
SELECT { t '07:32:00' }
```

The return is `2017-05-22 07:32:00.000`  (I'm using Sql-Server-2008)

If I don't include a proper time between the brackets, I get an error below:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

My question is; is this a "shortcut" for `getdate()` or some other similar function?

And, how can/should it be used?

Comment: They're ODBC escape characters.

Comment: @BaconBits, but why is the time expanded to a timestamp (incl today's date)?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make clear...How it the "t" used and are there others?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/date-time-and-timestamp-escape-sequences

Comment: @jarlh Dunno.  It doesn't return a timestamp on my SQL Server 2008 R2 system.  `t` is the code for `time`, and that's a valid data type in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Unfortunately, people were too quick to close your question, and I cannot provide an adequate enough answer in the comments. The duplicate question is not really answering the question you have. Anyhow, have a look at these two pages for explanation and reference: http://web.synametrics.com/winsqlescapeclause.htm and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/odbc-escape-sequences